# PHP Files downloading (source code) instead of running, sometimes

Tags: php, windows-7

I'm running Uniserver on windows 7, and it's been extremely difficult so far.

At first, only files in subdirectories would not run properly. Now though (after a restart), all files do not work.

Basically, instead of running, the source file is downloaded in my browser (unless the server isn't on - then I simply get the "Problem Loading Page" message).

When it was working, other problems occured, such as include files being echo'd instead of run.

Can someone guide me w/ regards to getting Uniserver to run cleanly and properly?

Thanks!

---

Edit:

Now when I browse to `http://localhost`, it shows a directory browsing interface like this: http://www.gobalakrishnan.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/04/directory-browsing.jpg

Edit: I reinstalled Uniserver and it's the same, except now the admin panel is working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's literally what you get when all you do is browse to `http://localhost/` and NOTHING else?

I believe this means that you have a redirect either in the core Apache configuration, or in your private .htaccess file, because you're being taken all the way into a WordPress directory that's not meant to be directly accessed.

Two Solutions to this current problem:

(1) Review your .htaccess file (perhaps temporarily rename it, or delete it **AFTER MAKING A BACKUP!!!!**
(2) Turn off "indexes" or "Directory indexes" (indexing?) in the Uniserver configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Your image looks to me like you dis-configured virtual dir in IIS.

Try in IIS to uncheck "Directory browsing" checkbox
Also, configure your browser to permit running active content/ scripts, etc.